# Select everything in a pre box when you click on it?

Tags: javascript, click, html-select, highlight, pre

The select() method only seems to work with textareas and input spaces, and I don't know javascript very well, so I'm not coming up with any solutions.  Does anyone know how to highlight everything in a pre box when you click on it?

What I'm trying to do is make it so a visitor can easily highlight everything in the pre so they can then copy and paste it.  I am currently using textareas, and switching to pres mean that the user can no longer give it focus, so they can't do control a.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, this is not possible. A workaround could be to create a `<textarea readonly="readonly">` and style it like a `<pre>` block.

Comment: This is a pretty good solution but having the ability to do "ctrl+A select all" on a non-textarea element would be great